# Separating interfaces and implementations

Tags: c#, design-patterns

Suppose I have a project A, which references project B. B has some classes defined within it, and A has an interface ISomething, whose implementation situated in A, and uses B's classes. Then I want to create project C and another implementation of A's interface, which uses C's classes. Here's the problem: I want to move implementations of this interface to corresponding projects so that I can define which project I want to use in build script and omit other. Nevertheless I want to save connection between interface and it's implementation for sake of tons of already existing code that uses this interface. So far I've been thinking over following options:

- Use adapter pattern in project A, which returns ISomething, references both implementations and adapts implementation of B if C is missing and vice versa. The con is that makes all interface-implementation relationship useless from my point of view
- Create project D, which contains interface, and is referenced by A,B and C, and then resolve in this project the interface to one of it's implementation. A project receives concrete instance and works with it. The con is that I need to create another library and pollute repository.

What option is better and are there any others?

Comment: Do you need to keep implementations in separate projects for a reason? i.e. don't want that code to exist in certain builds?

Comment: My main project is targeted for multiple platforms and I use script to generate a specific solution files depending on parameters, with which this script is run. What I want is to define new parameter which will specify what project I want to use in solution(B or C), that's why I want to move implementations in separate projects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would definitely go for Project D.

Sometimes you would see it in solutions where the interfaces aren't even shared, or meant to be shared and that's clearly overkill, but I'd say that for your situation it would be the best way to do it.

Now, what you might want to do is not just leave it as a dll or project reference, because

1. You will have to compile and link this project, and that will take time. Even if there is next to no code in that project, the Linking time will still occur.
2. You will have no easy way to version your interface, therefore editing the interface in one project with breaking changes will need immediate propagation on the other projects, and you will not know if you have done it already.

To avoid those two problems, I would create a **NuGet** package out of this Project D. You don't need to host it on NuGet.org, you can simply self-host it, either with an on-premises server, or, the simplest way: by pointing to a local or a shared folder.